# bellman ford algorithm

Tags: bellman-ford

It is said, "If a negative edge cycle is reachable from the source than the algorithm returns false".

What does this "reachable from source indicates"?

Look at the following image:

[image]

Can you give me some example in which this algorithm will return false if there exist a negative edge cycle reachable from source.

Note: I am new to algorithms.

Comment: http://www2.hawaii.edu/~suthers/courses/ics311f11/Notes/Topic-18.html

Answer (score 1):

What that means is that if there exists a cycle that has a total weight that is negative, then the algorithm cannot give an answer because repeatedly following the cycle "reduces" the weight of the path.  I don't see any negative weight cycles (by inspection) in the graph you show, so the stated limitation shouldn't be a concern in your case.

Edit: "reachable from source" means that the negative weight cycle is only a concern if it is reachable - meaning that a path from the specified source to some node in the negative weight cycle exists - from the start or source node.  Bellman Ford finds the shortest path from a distinguished node to all nodes reachable from that node.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry. but didn't get it. We find the shortest path from the source specified.

Answer (score 1):

When the algorithm is used to find shortest paths, the existence of negative cycles is a problem, preventing the algorithm from finding a correct answer. However, since it terminates upon finding a negative cycle, the Bellman-Ford algorithm can be used for applications in which this is the target to be sought - for example in cycle-cancelling techniques in network flow analysis.

Please refer this link:- http://evlm.stuba.sk/~partner2/DBfiles/Optimization/Dynamical%20optimization/Optimization_EN_Ford-Belman_algorithm.pdf